# Как в битриксе вызвать данные одного компонента в другом компоненте?

Tags: битрикс

Хотелось бы узнать, как в битриксе вызвать данные одного компонента в другом компоненте?

Например, есть слайдер, это первый компонент. Есть каталог товаров (описание, фото, кнопка заказа), это второй компонент.

Хочу делать так, чтобы в компоненте слайдера крутились товары.

Как можно добавить все данные товаров в слайдер?

Answer (score 2):

Из шаблона одного компонента можно вызывать другой компонент точно также, как Вы вызываете компонент на обычной странице:

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(...)
```